# C++ - pointer to array of template struct

Tags: c++, pointers

I want a const pointer to an array of a template struct. I'm getting an error, and I'm not very familiar with C++ so I'm not really sure where to go from here. Can someone please explain how to do this correctly and what I did wrong? Thanks in advance.

Struct:

```
template <typename T> struct FrequencyEntry {
    unsigned short freq;
    T result;
};
```

Code:

```
FrequencyEntry<std::string> arr[] = {
    {5, std::string("test")},
    {10, std::string("asdf")},
};

FrequencyEntry<std::string> * const arr_pointer = &arr;
```

The error occurs on that last line:

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'FrequencyEntry<T> (*)[2]' to 'FrequencyEntry<T> *const '
```

Comment: `&arr` is address of array, you  should assign `arr` only, read error message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The array decays to a pointer, so you do not need to pre-pend the address operator `&`:

```
FrequencyEntry<std::string> * const arr_pointer = arr;
```

Note that this is a `const` pointer, meaning that you cannot modify the pointer itself, but you can modify the object it points to via the pointer.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks!